# How do you work around the code complexity limit in scrutinizer-ci?

Tags: javascript, scrutinizer

I'm using scrutinizer-ci for an [open source project](https://github.com/nightfury7/universalbasics.js), and many of my files get an F simply because they are "too complex" or "too long". For example in [this](https://scrutinizer-ci.com/g/nightfury7/universalbasics.js/code-structure/master/js-file/src/ub.strings.charrange.js) file,  all my functions have C+ but the overall file score is F coz its "too complex". I mean [this function](https://scrutinizer-ci.com/g/nightfury7/universalbasics.js/code-structure/master/js-function/src/ub.strings.find.js%7CstringFuncs.smartIndexOf) looks relatively well written, but its F coz its too long. Is there a way to work around or disable this "feature"?

Yes I read all the docs, Yes I googled, Yes I looked all over on their website and FOSS issues but there is nothing mentioned about  disabling the complexity check, or making it more permissive.

The only workarounds (which are bad):

1. You can disable scrutinizer-ci from parsing certain files. How does that help?
2. You can disable the whole scrutinizer from certain commits. Again, pointless.